# Regex match exact number not if it exist in string

Tags: regex

My regex:

```
/3\b/
```

Matches:

```
103

134,256,3
```

I want it to only match the lone 3. The number 3 will be a dynamic number så the regex has to match that exact number and nothing else. It cant match if the number exists in another number like in 103, then it should not match. 256 should match only 256 in the above and so on. I am stuck. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a word boundary before it as well:

```
\b3\b
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match only 3 in line you can use anchors like this:

```
^3$
```

On the other hand if you want to match `3` in a line with more data you need to add an additional `\b` at your regex as [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) showed in her answer

Comment: as mentioned by Federico use ^3$ if you are looking for a single 3 as a value with no additional information. In other words not part of another string ( "number 3") or even another number ("1234"), just a 3 by itself.